# Simple interval/range intersection with overflow

Tags: c#, c++, overflow, range, intervals

I'm writing a physical memory manager that gets some intervals of memory from the BIOS that are not used by crucial system data. Each interval has `0 <= start <= 2^32 - 1` and `0 <= length <= 2^32`. I have already filtered out the zero-length intervals.

Given two intervals S and T, I want to detect *how* they intersect. For example, does S start before T and end within T (picture *a*)? Or does S start before T and end after T (picture *c*)?

You'd think the solution is trivial:

```cpp
uint s_end = s_start + s_length;
uint t_end = t_start + t_length;

if (s_start < t_start)
    // S starts before T
else if (s_start < t_end)
    // S starts within T
else
    // S starts after T

if (s_end <= t_start)
    // S ends before T
else if (s_end <= t_end)
    // S ends within T
else
    // S ends after T
```

The problem is overflow: I am technically limited to a 32-bit integer and the intervals can (and often do) use the whole range of available integers. For example in figure *b*, `t_end` equals 0 due to overflow. Or even, as in figure *f* `t_start = t_end = s_start = 0` while `t_length != 0`.

**How can I make these interval intersection conditions work with overflow taken into account?**

The overflow screws up my conditions, but I *really* can't use a 64-bit integer for this (that would be easiest). I know it must be possible using some clever reshuffling of my conditions and using addition and subtraction, but after making endless diagrams and thinking about it for hours, I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around it.

[image: Some examples of intervals]

<sup>While my problem is with 32-bit integers, in this image I used 4-bit integers just to simplify it. The problem remains the same.</sup>

Comment: If you had inclusive start/end pairs, it would be easier, because there wouldn't be any overflow. Just subtract 1 from the end - that would cause a problem if you had 0-length intervals, but you don't.

Comment: @harold These intervals represent ranges of bytes. To represent all the bytes in a 32-bit system I would again end up with start 0 end 0 when using inclusive start/end pairs.

Comment: No you wouldn't, you'd end up with [0, 0xFFFFFFFF]. You can't include 0 *twice*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to treat an end of 0 as a special case. Weaving this into the if-statements, it becomes:

```
uint s_end = s_start + s_length;
uint t_end = t_start + t_length;

if (s_start < t_start)
    // S starts before T
else if (t_end == 0 || s_start < t_end)
    // S starts within T
else
    // S starts after T

if (s_end != 0 && s_end <= t_start)
    // S ends before T
else if (t_end == 0 || s_end == t_end
    || (s_end != 0 && s_end <= t_end))
    // S ends within T
else
    // S ends after T
```

This looks correct.

Comment: Under your definition, you can't even do the first two lines (calculate `s_end` and `t_end`) safely - they can overflow.  BTW, your comment below my answer is valid - lemme think about this a little more.

Comment: @kfmfe04 There are two cases: it doesn't overflow and the value is `1 <= end <= 2^32-1` (since I have no zero-length intervals), or it does overflow and the value is 0. Therefore I added the additional if-conditions. When it overflowed (overflew? :P) then I know the length is the maximum possible.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the issue is, if you want your ranges to span all of n-bits, any calculations based on start/end has the potential to overflow.

So the trick is to do a linear transform to a place where your start/end calculations do not overflow, do your calcs, and then linear transform back.

**NOTES**

Below the *we can safely call end() now* line, you can call the ordering checks (your original code) and it will be safe since the ordering is preserved during a linear transform.

Also, as I noted in the previous post, there is a special boundary case where even if you do this transform, you will overflow (where you span the entire line) - but you can code for that special boundary condition.

**OUTPUT**

5 11

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>

using type = uint8_t;

struct segment
{
    type start, length;
    type end() const { return start + length; }
};

static segment
intersect( segment s, segment t )
{
    type shift = std::min( s.start, t.start );

    // transform so we can safely call end()
    s.start -= shift;     // doesn't affect length
    t.start -= shift;     // doesn't affect length

    // we can safely call end() now ----------------------------------------------
    type u_start  = std::max( s.start, t.start );
    type u_end    = std::min( s.end(), t.end() );
    type u_length = u_end - u_start;

    segment u{ u_start, u_length };

    // transform back
    u.start += shift;

    return u;
}

int main()
{
    segment s{ 3, 13 }, t{ 5, 11 };
    segment u = intersect( s, t );

    std::cerr << uint32_t( u.start ) << " " << uint32_t( u.length ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no mistakes in my diagrams. There are 16 values (16 gaps between two marks): 0 through F. Also, in a 3-bit system there are 8 values: 0 through 7. So starting at 0, to have everything in an interval, the length of the interval is 8, not 6. In a 1 bit system there are 2 values: 0 and 1 (2^1 - 1). Starting at 0, my full interval has a length of 2 (2^1).

Comment: @Virtlink if you choose to have 16 values for intervals, your start and end points will have to go from 0 - 0 (which looks like overflow).  Anyhow, my answer still stands.  If you want to use the entire range of 16 values, you can do it with a combination of the shift (so you can do start/end math without overflow) and the cheat (simplification at the boundary where length==15 or length==16 depending on your convention and requirements).  But I would comment heavily to avoid confusion (explaining why you need all this extra complexity).

Comment: I'm writing a physical memory manager that gets some ranges of memory from the BIOS that are not used by crucial system data. Each range has `0 <= start <= 2^32 - 1` and `0 <= length <= 2^32`. It is not a requirement that the lengths are non-zero, just that I already filtered out the zero-length ranges. You code with `if (length==max_len)` won't work for most cases. For example, with 16 values, if for S I start at value 15 (the last value) with a length of 1, I end up with an end of `15 + 1 = 0`. Yes, it not only looks like overflow, it actually is.

Comment: @Virtlink now you are providing more useful information.  Let's play with 16 values.  Show me an example of `s_start`, `s_length`, `t_start`, `t_length`, and what you expect to get in the intersection `u_start`, `u_length`.  Give me the crazy case where you can't get any algorithm to work (boundary case ok, but inputs must be valid).

Comment: For example my figure _b_: `s_start = 3`, `t_start = 5`, `s_length = 13`, `t_length = 11`. Then my code gives _S starts before T_ (correct) and _S ends before T_ (incorrect) since `s_end = s_start + s_length = 0` and `s_end <= t_start`... Or my figure _d_: `s_start = 6`, `t_start = 5`, `s_length = 9`, `t_length = 11`. Then I get _S starts after T_ (incorrect, since `t_end = 0`) and _S ends after T_ (also incorrect, should be _S ends within T_).

Comment: @Virtlink I have revised the answer based on your examples, if you call your original code at the point I designated, you should get the right answers without overflow (calling your original code after the transform is valid because ordering is preserved during a linear transform).

Comment: I see what you did there, look good. +1 from me. But aren't there three boundary cases: where T spans the entire range, where S spans the entire range, and where S _and_ T span the entire range?

Comment: @Virtlink It's actually quite simple.  If T spans the entire range, the intersection is S, whatever S is.  If S spans the entire range, the intersection is T, whatever T is.  If they both span the entire range, the intersection is the entire range, but you don't need to check for this one since the first case will cover you and give you the right answer.  So at most, you need to check with two ifs.

Comment: I think I found another issue. What if S starts at 0 and T runs to the end? Then `shift` is 0, so `end()` will again overflow for T.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code does not enumerate all the cases. For example the intervals could also start or end at the same point.

To solve the overflow problem you could try to add different math based on the start comparison that will not include computing the ends at all. Something like:

```
if (s_start < t_start)
{
    // S starts before T
    uint start_offset = t_start - s_start;
    if (start_offset < s_length)
    {
        if (s_length - start_offset < t_length)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else ...
    } else ...
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the general direction I think is correct, but changing the conditions also involves changing the signs. I'm not sure how to go about it. By the way, I forgot to mention the intervals all have a non-zero length, so they cannot have the same start and end.

Comment: it looks a bit spaghetti, but with several extra checks you could avoid this issue too - see the edit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you do with conditions like (f), since 32-bit t_length will be 0 there.
Assuming you've managed this case somehow when you were filtering out length=0, which can mean both 0 and 2^32, the basic idea is this:

```
bool s_overflows=false;
if(s_start>0)//can't have overflow with s_start==0,
{
    uint32 s_max_length=_UI32_MAX-s_start+1;
    if(s_length==s_max_length) s_overflow=true;
}
bool t_overflows=false;
if(t_start>0)
{
    uint32 t_max_length=_UI32_MAX-t_start+1;
    if(t_length==t_max_length) t_overflow=true;
}
```

Then you just do your calculations, but if s_overflow is true, you don't calculate s_end -- you don't need it, since you already know it's 0x100000000. The same for t_overflow. Since these are already special cases, just like start=0, they shouldn't complicate your code much.

Comment: Indeed, `t_length` is 0x100000000 for _f_ but due to overflow it becomes 0. The whole issue is that I couldn't figure out how to deal with this in my if-statements. But I think I found a solution (posted here too).